# Using the prefix "be-"?

Tags: prefixes

I read somewhere that the prefix *be-* can be used as a causative and this got me thinking. Does this mean that *because* means *to cause to cause* or *to make cause*?

Comment: [Here's](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_definition_of_the_prefix_be) a good summary of the main different meanings of **be-** as a prefix. 1) thoroughly *(bespeckled)*, 2) to cause to seem *(belittle)*, 3) to provide with *(beloved)*. But as the answers indicate, *because* doesn't use this prefix - it's **by-**.

Answer (score 2):

From OED (the other one):

**[because](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=because)**

> c.1300, bi cause "by cause," modeled on Fr. par cause. Originally a
>   phrase, often followed by a subordinate clause introduced by that or
>   why. One word from c.1400. As an adverb from late 14c.

Comment: Thankyou very much for this. I have also just thought of the words 'bemoan' and 'befall'. do these therefore their meanings as by moan(ing) or by fall(ing) have?

Comment: [_bemoan_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bemoan&searchmode=none) comes from Old English 'to bemoan, wail, lament'.

[_befall_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=befall&searchmode=none) comes from Old English 'to deprive of; fall to, be assigned to' but also from from befall, and befall from be- "by, about" + feallan (see fall).

Answer (score 0):

The word 'because' originated [from 'bi cause' or 'by cause'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=because) and not be-cause. So because does not mean to cause to cause.